# Is it normal to have a 0.0 P-value when I ran a pearson's correlation test in python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, data-analysis, pearson-correlation

I had a dataset consisting of three variables. I ran a Pearson's correlation coefficient test to see the result, but it shows that the p-value is 0.0. I was unsure whether I made a mistake or 0.0 p-value is possible. Can anyone tell me if I made a mistake or is it normal?

Here is my code:

```
new_death = df['New deaths'].values
cases = df['New cases'].values
vaccinations = df['New vaccinations'].values
list_of_vars = [new_death,cases,vaccinations]
results = [scipy.stats.pearsonr(*pair) for pair in combinations(list_of_vars, 2)]
```

And here is the result of this code.

```
[(0.9591135831040322, 0.0),
 (0.5663918183925666, 0.0),
 (0.6125207790335854, 0.0)]
```

Comment: What are the lengths of the arrays?  Can show the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough samples for the correlation to be very precise, you can get a p-value of 0, as you can see from the [documentation on pearson](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html#scipy.stats.pearsonr).

Other than posting your data, you could try running the test with a different dataset.